# Missing "ExampleBrowser" assembly (namespace) [helix-3d-toolkit]

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

In most of the Helix 3d wpf examples (source files) posted in GitHub, there is a reference to "Example Browser" (using ExampleBrowser;) in the .cs files. I cannot find any assembly defining a reference to this namespace in the packages obtained from Nuget (HelixToolkit and HelixToolkit.Wpf). I commented this line out and solution builds OK and app runs OK.

Anyone has any idea where this line comes from or where the assembly is?

Thanks in advance.

ikonuk

Comment: Hello. I think you are mixing two different things: the Nugget-Package, and the Example solution. It is normal to delete/replace the references to any `ExampleBrowser` namespace. These are specific to the example solution, and you should ignore it, unless you code directly in this solution.

Comment: An other example: if I give you part of my functions/classes to solve one of your problem, some external namespaces will be referenced such as 'System.IO' or 'HelixToolkit.Wpf', and you will have to import them to make it work. But you may also find references to `TestBob.Model` which doesn't make sense for you. And you will have to delete or redirect the references to this namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you clone the repo of helix-toolkit you'll see that in the Helix-Toolkit solution there is a separate project called example browser for showcasing various use cases. Nuget packages only contain the helix-toolkit itself without the examples